# Open weather map API , couldn't get JSON, but getting JSONP and couldnt make asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, jquery, heatmap, weather-api

Am getting longitude and latitude values from google's webserivce and passing the values to open weather map api to get the temperature values. Code below

```
function getWeatherData(latitude, longitude) {
                            var temperature = 0;

                            var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=";
                            url = url + latitude;
                            url = url + "&lon=";
                            url = url + longitude;
                            url = url + "&cnt=1";


                            $
                            .ajax({
                                type : "POST",
                                dataType : "jsonp",
                                url : url + "&callback=?",
                                async : false,
                                success : function(data) {
                                    temperature = data.list[0].main.temp ;
                                    alert (temperature);

                                },
                                error : function(errorData) {
                                    alert("Error while getting weather data :: "+errorData.status);
                                }
                            });

                            return temperature;
```

So for this URL

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/city?lat=22.572646&lon=88.36389500000001&cnt=1
```

Am getting the below JSON response properly in the browser

```
{
    "message": 0.016,
    "cod": "200",
    "calctime": "",
    "cnt": 1,
    "list": [{
        "id": 1275004,
        "name": "Kolkata",
        "coord": {
            "lon": 88.36972,
            "lat": 22.569719
        },
        "distance": 0.999,
        "main": {
            "temp": 301.15,
            "pressure": 998,
            "humidity": 88,
            "temp_min": 301.15,
            "temp_max": 301.15
        },
        "dt": 1371217800,
        "wind": {
            "speed": 3.1,
            "deg": 150
        },
        "clouds": {
            "all": 40
        },
        "weather": [{
            "id": 721,
            "main": "Haze",
            "description": "haze",
            "icon": "50n"
        }]
    }]
}
```

But while trying to hit the same using jQuery's ajax, I have no option except to get the values as JSONP, **unable to get it as JSON**

Since am unable to get JSON response, am not able to make the call asynchronous.

I need to make asynchronous false. **Because of this every time, the value temperature is set to 0 and am not able to get the actual temperature value which i get from the ajax call**

Please help

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need to return the value using a callback.

Comment: JSONP cannot be POST, nor synchronous.

Comment: I need to make asynchronous false and this stops me to return the actual temperature value. Can you please help me saying how to do it actually ?

Comment: ^^^ What SLaks said! JSONP isn't "really" ajax, it inserts a script tag instead, so GET and async is the only way to do that, setting anything else in $.ajax is just ignored.

Comment: I couldn't understand. really sorry for that :( . so now how i will get the actual temperature value. The function always returns the value 0 as it is not waiting for the ajax call

Comment: @SLaks : Can you please help me on this. ? pls

Comment: if the alert() works, simply cut and paste whatever you did after getWeatherData(..,..),  into getWeatherData() inside the success() method.

Comment: it would make ajax call again ...!! in getWeatherData function, the ajax call is there .. do u mean to say that again in the success block, we have to write the code ?? not understanding :(

Comment: Hi ...i have some quesries regarding the weather API as well. Which information do we use to show the weather icon with our data.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using JQuery then you could use a defer and promise. Something like this:

```
function getWeatherData(latitude, longitude) {
    var temperature = 0;
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=";
    url += latitude;
    url += "&lon=";
    url += longitude;
    url += "&cnt=1";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url + "&callback=?",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            temperature = data.list[0].main.temp;
            alert(temperature);
            dfd.resolve(temperature);
        },
        error: function (errorData) {
            alert("Error while getting weather data :: " + errorData.status);
        }
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

This will cause it to return the value once temperature has been resolved through the ajax call. I was using a weather API and had this same exact problem.